# How to record audio (input and output) via a website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I'm very new to web development, so please do bear this in mind:

Essentially, I'm trying to create a button to put on my website, that will record any audio (input and output) for anything you are doing on your PC - and then subsequently upload it to storage which is provided by your website hosting company.

An example of this is: https://www.screencapture.com/blog/how-to-record-streaming-audio.html

The difference being, I need a button built into my website, and that the audio recording is automatically uploaded to my database on the host (when you press the button to end the recording) - rather than download the audio recording locally like the example given above.

Would this at all be possible?

Many thanks

Comment: in windows, you can record "output" by enabling the stereo mix device and recording from that - of course, a browser can't do that, the user would have to set all that up beforehand ... as for other systems (MacOS, linux, android, ios) - that would be done differently, but again, something the user needs to set up

Comment: @JaromandaX how would i go about even trying to develop a function built into my website that can do what I need? to the point where regardless of OS - it seamlessly works on the website?

Comment: you can't, because a browser can't make the necessary adjustments to the operating system settings - zero chance of doing what you want without having instructions for all possible operating systems (and, in the case of linux, the multiple ways audio is set up)

Comment: @JaromandaX how come the website i linked is able to do so?

Comment: ok, maybe I'm wrong - so, there's a website that can record any audio you play (not just in the browser, but as you say *anything you are doing on your PC*)  on computer? what's the website? Perhaps I can see what it's doing by looking at the code

Comment: @JaromandaX yes exactly that, here it is: https://www.screencapture.com/blog/how-to-record-streaming-audio.html

it's free so if you dont mind checking it out for me and seeing how it works? I would really appreciate it, thanks

Comment: nope, doesn't record **AUDIO** at all

Comment: do you have "stereo mix" enabled as a recording device (assuming you run windows of course)

Comment: @JaromandaX unfortunately I do not as I run MacOS, I’m quite surprised that the site doesn’t record audio